# Can anyone tell me what happens in for loop

Tags: javascript

Here is the code that computes 2 10 , using for loop :
How did the 1024 answer come?

```
var result = 1;
for ( var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1)
result = result * 2;
console . log ( result );
//  1024
```

Comment: If you go line by line and do this by hand, do you not end up with 1024? What makes you think it shouldn't be 1024? If you are just asking how a for loop works then you should use google for that.

Comment: You have calculated 2^10 in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically

> 1024 = 2<sup>10</sup>

(2 * 2 ... 10 times)

The *for* loop loops 10 times, each time result is multiplied by 2 (was 1 initially).

Indenting you code gives

```
var result = 1;

for ( var counter = 0; counter < 10; counter = counter + 1)
    result = result * 2;

console . log ( result );  // display result in console
```

Comment: @Mohamed Check my vote cast (and my "hat"!), I vote up a lot. And I would have done the same for this question if I'd have thought it brings a plus to the community. Despite your request, I cannot vote for a question if it does not deserve it, in my opinion.

Comment: Ok Thanks. There were should I ask these types of questions?

Comment: Your question is fine, and I didn't down vote it. Unfit questions for this site are closed. That's not the case. Don't know why your question is that down voted.. maybe the thought you could have worked a bit more by yourself? Maybe write a bit more about *what you think the result should have been* in the question? See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't have a block (`{}`) around the for loop statements, only the first statement is in the loop (`result = result * 2;`), so it's multiplying the result with 2, 10 times, i.e.

```
result = 1 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 * 2
```

and after that you are outputing that result (`1024`).

Answer (score 1):

Your `for loop` only runs `result = result * 2`.

Now, your `result` initial value is  `1`. Then this will do the operation of `result * 2` for 10 times which gives the result of `1024`

```
2
4
8
16
32
64
128
256
512
1024
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (statement 1; statement 2; statement 3) {
    code block to be executed
}
```

Statement 1 is executed before the loop (the code block) starts.

Statement 2 defines the condition for running the loop (the code block).

Statement 3 is executed each time after the loop (the code block) has been executed.

In your case, this loop runs 10 times. In your "statement 1", you assign counter to 0.Then, you define the condition, which is that the for loop will run until counter is = or > 10 (so until the condition isn't met). On "statement 3" you are just adding one to counter at the end of every loop.

Therefore, you are multiplying variable "result" (which is assigned a value of 1) times 2, **10 times**. After that, the console.log just prints the result variable.

```
//2^10 = 1024
```

hope this helps, here's a link to for loop syntax: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp